# How to check if any of the elements satisfy a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to check if any of the elements in my selector satisfies a specific condition?

Currently I use:

```
var isSatisfied = false;
$("#myUL li").each(function() {
    if($(this).data("myconditon") === true) {
        isSatisfied = true;
    }
});
// Use isSatisfied here
```

This seems overly complex to do a simple job. 
What I'm looking for is something like [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C#.

Comment: what you want to achieve? you want any event to bind with those selected elements?

Comment: No. I just want to know if any of the elements satisfy the condition. I don't want to do anything with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-functionindex), still you will have to do the condition check

```
var isSatisfied = $("#myUL li").is(function () {
    return $(this).data("myconditon") === true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isSatisfied = !!$("#myUL li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("myconditon") === true;
}).length;
```

`.filter()`, as its name suggests, retains only those items for which the callback returns true. So we end up with a jQuery stack. By querying its length, and coercing that to a boolean, you end up with your desired boolean var `isSatisfied`.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't stop when it find the first false solution, which may be a problem if the check is expensive.